# C Program output differs on different machines

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following program -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int counter = 0;

    int responses[28];
    printf("Enter student section values: \n");
    while(counter != 27) {
        scanf("%d", &responses[counter]);
        counter++;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int arrayBlank[100];
    int temp = 0;
    int past = 0;
    int present = 0;
    int future = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        if((i - 1) < 0 || (i + 1 >= counter)) {
            ;
        }
        else {
            past = responses[i - 1];
            present = responses[i];
            future = responses[i + 1];
            if(present == past || present == future) {
                temp = present;
                flag=1;
                arrayBlank[temp]++;
            } else {
                arrayBlank[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if(flag == 0) {
        printf("\nThe order input does not assign any adjacent students from the same team\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        int chut[28];
        int index = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
            index = responses[i];
            chut[index]++;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
            if(chut[i] <= 0 || chut[i] > 26) {
                chut[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("\nThe order input currently assigns adjacent students from the same team.\n");
        printf("\nTeam Students\n");
        for(i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
            if(chut[i] != 0) {
                printf("%d %d\n", i, chut[i]);
            }
        }
        //1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 5 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically for a given range of numbers, it checks if there is any particular number in the given entries that has an adjacent value which is the same as that number. If there is, it will just print how many times a particular element appeared in the given range of numbers.

**Example -** For a list of numbers

> 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 5 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8

The program execution would be like -

```
Enter student section values: 1 2 3 3 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 5 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8

The order input currently assigns adjacent students from the same team.

Team Students
 1 3
 2 3
 3 4
 4 2
 5 4
 6 2
 7 3
 8 4
 9 2
```

**Issue :** I am not able to figure out the reason why the output is different on different machines and how I could fix that. For example, the output is correct on my Macbook running the program with XCode although it is different when I run it on a Linux machine with gcc compiler (Big Endian machine). I am not sure if the Endianess has anything to do with the outputs being different though.

On a Little Endian Linux machine -

[image]

On a Big Endian Linux machine -

[image]

On an online compiler ([Tutorial's Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php)) -

[image]

Comment: You forgot to initialize `arrayBlank` so it starts with garbage. That's just one of many problems.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed that although that doesn't fix the issue as you said.

Comment: Do big-endian x64 machines even exist?

Comment: `chut` is also not initialized.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was chut wasn't initialized aswell.

Comment: regarding these two lines: 'index = responses[i];
            chut[index]++;'  there is no reason to believe the value input from the user is in the range 0...27 (the valid range of offsets into chut).  So when any value is outside that range, including <0, the result will be undefined behaviour and possibly a seg fault event.

Comment: If you read the C Standard, you'll see the term "undefined behavior".  It's easy to write C programs with this attribute. You've proved it! Now the trick is writing a program with well-defined behavior.  Note you've read only 26 inputs, but you're processing 27 in the final loop. That 27th array element could be any junk. Also, accepting advice from comments but not changing the bad code in the question is quite rude.

Comment: if you compile with the -Wstrict_prototypes parameters, then this line: int main() {' will not compile.  suggest using: 'int main(void) {'  however, the posted statements indicate no warnings were enabled.  should at least enable most warnings by: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'

Answer (score 3):

The main problem, as far as I can see, is that you haven't initialized `arrayBlank` and are using it in:

```
arrayBlank[temp]++;
```

That certainly is cause for undefined behavior. I would initialize `arrayBlank` to zero using

```
int arrayBlank[100] = {0};
```

The secondary problem is that the loop counter to read the data is not right. Instead of:

```
while(counter != 27) {
    scanf("%d", &responses[counter]);
```

use:

```
while(counter != 28) {
    scanf("%d", &responses[counter]);
```

When you use `counter != 27` to stop, the last element of `responses`, which can be accessed using index `27` is never read from file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that however that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: The problem was chut aswell as arrayBlank weren't initialized. I initialized them to {0} and that fixed the issue.

Comment: @NatureDevil, glad you figured out the other problem without outside help :)